# Card Class in Ruby

Tags: ruby, class, playing-cards

I am fairly new to ruby and am developing a card class. For the most part I got it to work when ever I use a number to define a rank, however when I define the rank as a K (King) it throws back an error message(uninitialized constant). if someone could show me and explain to me what I am doing wrong I would greatly appreciate it

This is my card class

```
class Card
  attr_accessor :rank, :suit 

  def initialize(the_rank, the_suit)
    @rank = the_rank
    @suit = the_suit
    @symbols = [nil, nil, "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K", "A"]
  end

  def rank
    return @rank
  end

  def suit
    return @suit
  end

  def color
    if @suit == "C" || @suit == "S"
      color = "Black" 
      else
      color = "Red"
    end
  end

  def to_s
    return "#{@symbols[@rank]}#{@suit}"
  end
end
```

This is a simple test script I have it runs the 7 of clubs fine but can not run the Jack of hearts.

```
c = Card.new(7, "C") 
print c, "\n"

print c.rank, "\n"

print c.suit, "\n"

print c.color, "\n"


c = Card.new(J, "H") 
print c, "\n"

print c.rank, "\n"

print c.suit, "\n"

print c.color, "\n"
```

Comment: what is the full error?

Comment: BBB.rb:13:in `<main>': uninitialized constant J (NameError)

Comment: That's because you have the line `c = Card.new(J, "H")`. Should be `c = Card.new("J", "H")` instead, I guess. Note: `J` -> `"J"`.

Comment: When I try that I receive this message: AAA.rb:27:in `[]': no implicit conversion of String into Integer (TypeError)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
c = Card.new(J, "H")
```

try

```
c = Card.new("J", "H")
```

This is because `J` doesn't have any meaning, it's not a defined object; But the string `"J"`, Ruby recognizes that object as a string, thus no error

Comment: When I try that I receive this message: AAA.rb:27:in `[]': no implicit conversion of String into Integer (TypeError)

Comment: What line of code are you executing when you receive this error?

Comment: BBB is my test script and AAA is the class script

Comment: Okay.... that didn't answer my question.  The line of code in your error is 27.  What is the actual code that is being run on line 27 in AAA.

Comment: return "#{@symbols[@rank]}#{@suit}"

Comment: ahhh, I see.  So you're going to have to refactor your code a bit because "J" isn't a valid array index.  Looking at what you're returning from to_s, you can just `return "#{@rank}#{@suit}"`